# Clarification in R-CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am learning object detection using R-CNN...

I have the images and the annotation file which gives the bounding box for the object

I understand these steps in R-CNN,

Using selective search to get the proposed regions

Make all the region same size

Feed those images in CNN

Save the feature maps and feed to SVM for classification

---

In training, I took all the objects (only the objects from images not the background) and feed to the CNN and then train the feature maps in SVM for classification.

In every blogs, all are saying in R-CNN, there are three parts, 
1st -selective search
2nd -CNN
3rd -BBox Regression

But, I don't get the deep explanation of the BBox Regression.

I understand the IOU(Intercept over Union) to check the BBox accuracy.

Could you please help me to learn how this BBox Regression is used to get the coordinates of the object.

Comment: Hi! If you could make your question more focused to a single issue, give some context about this single issue, provide code & explanation what is the problem and what you did to solve it, you might get more use of this site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain about the BBox regression working which is as mentioned below.

Like you mentioned it happens in multiple stages.

1. Selective Search:

   1. Generate initial sub-segmentation, we generate many candidates or part regions.
   2. Use greedy algorithm to recursively combine similar regions into larger ones.
   3. Use the generated regions to produce the final candidate region proposals.
2. CNN and BBox Regression:

   The regressor is a CNN with convolutional layers, and fully connected layers, but in the last fully connected layer, it does not apply sigmoid or softmax, which is what is typically used in classification, as the values correspond to probabilities. Instead, what this CNN outputs are four values (,,ℎ,), where (,) specify the values of the position of the left corner and (ℎ,) the height and width of the window. In order to train this NN, the loss function will penalize when the outputs of the NN are very different from the labelled (,,ℎ,) in the training set.

Comment: @vishak raj -If you think I have answered your question, please help by upvoting!